# Brakes smoke and car slows down when driving

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, hyundai, accent

When I drive my 2003 Hyundai Accent (manual transmission), the car begins to slow down, won't accelerate and the brakes begins to smoke.

I took the car to the shop and they said it was my brake hoses and that my brakes were being applied somehow. So I said are you sure that the problem, they said yes and fixed it.

I picked my car up few days later and the same problem happened again, so took the car back and the guy tells me that it's my brake caliper. So I had both of them fixed yesterday and the car did the same thing coming home from work today.
The mechanic tells me it because of the snow, I said no that has nothing to do with it.

Just not sure what's the problem, I've already spent $900 and have no more to spend. So the car is back in their shop again this evening. Please help, I'm so confused.

Comment: It could very well be the calipers but if both wheels are locking up I would look elsewhere first.  If the vehicle is equipped with ABS I've seen a faulty hydraulic unit cause it.  Have the master cylinder checked as well.

Comment: thank you i will check to see if my car has and ABS unit .

Comment: My car doesnt have and abs on it

Comment: If you drive, your front wheels should get very hot due to the problem. What about the rear wheels?

Comment: When you say you "had them fixed" ... what exactly was done to the calipers?

Comment: Go to a different shop.  They are ripping you off.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at the [Brake Booster](https://repairpal.com/estimator/honda/accord/brake-booster-replacement-cost) and especially at the vacuum-system there.

Genreally, without ABS, you only have the following components

- The break lines, can be leaky. You should see that you loose brake-fluid then. Also, if you press the pedal it will slowly loose pressure under your foot.
- Break cylinders, can be rusted. This will cause the pads to not be properly retracted after you apply the breaks. Can cause the disks to warm up.
- Master brake cylinder. Could be leaky. Could cause the break pads not to retract after applying force.
- Worn off or corroded disks or pads. Can cause scratching or warm up of disks, especially when the is no more material left on the pads, while you break.
- Brake booster. Should normally only affect the amount of force you need to apply the breaks, but it is supported by the vacuum system of your car, so if there is something wrong ... maybe.